# What are the best free alternative research tool for the Nuzzel?

Tags: windows, android, web-apps, monitoring, research

I am looking for a free research and monitoring tool for getting the latest news in the digital marketing industry and tech news. Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Comment: This is vague. Best by what metric? What more than a web browser do you imagine you need?

Comment: [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints. Your question lacks essential details, like what features you need (research has many facettes), how much it may cost. So please **[edit]** your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[FlibBoard](https://flipboard.com/) is a good alternative. Depending on needs, [paper.li](https://paper.li) might be also good

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).